# Dart Language: MessageEvent.source not working properly on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dart, postmessage

I'm starting a listener on a MessageEvent, as follows:

```dart
window.onMessage.listen((MessageEvent e) {
    if (e.source == newWindow) {
        // Do something.
    }
});
```

And I'm opening "newWindow" like this:

```dart
newWindow = window.open("some_page.html", "");
```

**Now let's get to the unexpected behavior:**

```dart
 (e.source == newWindow)
```

**Dart returns TRUE, while JavaScript (build from Dart Editor) returns FALSE.**

Just to clarify, when "newWindow" sends a message to its opener (via window.opener.postMessage), my application should accept the message, since "source equals to newWindow". And it is, in fact, working. However just on Dart code. When the application is executed via JavaScript, this doesn't work. The verifying of "e.source equals to newWindow" returns false.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: I think this is a bug to report at http://dartbug.com.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thanks! Done: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21747